# When routing mswjs/data populates the database with new items and removes the previous one, making it inaccessible

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit, msw, next-redux-wrapper

I use `next-redux-wrapper`, `MSW`, `@mswjs/data` and `redux-toolkit` for storing my data in a store as well as mocking API calls and fetching from a mock Database.

I have the following scenario happening to me.

1. I am on page `/content/editor` and in the console and terminal, I can see the data was fetched from the mock database and hydrated from `getStaticProps` of `Editor.js`. So now IDs 1 to 6 are inside the store accessible.
2. Now I click on the PLUS icon to create a new project. I fill out the dialog and press "SAVE". a POST request starts, it's pending and then it gets fulfilled. The new project is now in the mock DB as well as in the store, I can see IDs 1 to 7 now.
3. Since I clicked "SAVE" and the POST request was successful, I am being routed to `/content/editor/7` to view the newly created project.
4. Now I am on Page `[id].js`, which also fetched data from the mock DB and then it gets stored and hydrated into the redux store. The idea is, it takes the previous store's state and spreads it into the store, with the new data (if there are any).
5. Now the ID 7 no longer exists. And IDs 1 to 6 also don't exist anymore, instead, I can see in the console and terminal that IDs 8 to 13 were created, and the previous ones are no more.

Obviously, this is not great. When I create a new project and then switch the route, I should be able to access the newly created project as well as the previously created ones. But instead, they all get overwritten.

It either has something to do with the `next-redux-wrapper` or `MSW`, but I am not sure how to make it work. I need help with it. I will post some code now:

### Code

#### getStaticProps

```js
// path example: /content/editor
// Editor.js

export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(
  (store) =>
    async ({ locale }) => {
      const [translation] = await Promise.all([
        serverSideTranslations(locale, ['editor', 'common', 'thesis']),
        store.dispatch(fetchProjects()),
        store.dispatch(fetchBuildingBlocks()),
      ]);

      return {
        props: {
          ...translation,
        },
      };
    }
);
```

```js
// path example: /content/editor/2
// [id].js
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(
  (store) =>
    async ({ locale, params }) => {
      const { id } = params;

      const [translation] = await Promise.all([
        serverSideTranslations(locale, ['editor', 'common', 'thesis']),
        store.dispatch(fetchProjects()),
        // store.dispatch(fetchProjectById(id)), // issue: fetching by ID returns null
        store.dispatch(fetchBuildingBlocks()),
      ]);

      return {
        props: {
          ...translation,
          id,
        },
      };
    }
);
```

#### Mock Database

##### Factory

I am going to shorten the code to the relevant bits. I will remove properties for a project, as well es helper functions to generate data.

```js
const asscendingId = (() => {
  let id = 1;
  return () => id++;
})();

const isDevelopment =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.STORYBOOK || false;

export const projectFactory = () => {
  return {
    id: primaryKey(isDevelopment ? asscendingId : nanoid),
    name: String,
    // ... other properties
  }
};

export const createProject = (data) => {
  return {
    name: data.name,
    createdAt: getUnixTime(new Date()),
    ...data,
  };
};

/**
 * Create initial set of tasks
 */
export function generateMockProjects(amount) {
  const projects = [];
  for (let i = amount; i >= 0; i--) {
    const project = createProject({
      name: faker.lorem.sentence(faker.datatype.number({ min: 1, max: 5 })),
      dueDate: date(),
      fontFamily: getRandomFontFamily(),
      pageMargins: getRandomPageMargins(),
      textAlign: getRandomTextAlign(),
      pageNumberPosition: getRandomPageNumberPosition(),
      ...createWordsCounter(),
    });
    projects.push(project);
  }
  return projects;
}
```

##### API Handler

I will shorten this one to GET and POST requests only.

```js
import { db } from '../../db';

export const projectsHandlers = (delay = 0) => {
  return [
    rest.get('https://my.backend/mock/projects', getAllProjects(delay)),
    rest.get('https://my.backend/mock/projects/:id', getProjectById(delay)),
    rest.get('https://my.backend/mock/projectsNames', getProjectsNames(delay)),
    rest.get(
      'https://my.backend/mock/projects/name/:id',
      getProjectsNamesById(delay)
    ),
    rest.post('https://my.backend/mock/projects', postProject(delay)),
    rest.patch(
      'https://my.backend/mock/projects/:id',
      updateProjectById(delay)
    ),
  ];
};

function getAllProjects(delay) {
  return (request, response, context) => {
    const projects = db.project.getAll();
    return response(context.delay(delay), context.json(projects));
  };
}

function postProject(delay) {
  return (request, response, context) => {
    const { body } = request;
    if (body.content === 'error') {
      return response(
        context.delay(delay),
        context.status(500),
        context.json('Server error saving this project')
      );
    }

    const now = getUnixTime(new Date());
    const project = db.project.create({
      ...body,
      createdAt: now,
      maxWords: 10_000,
      minWords: 7000,
      targetWords: 8500,
      potentialWords: 1500,
      currentWords: 0,
    });
    return response(context.delay(delay), context.json(project));
  };
}
```

```js
// all handlers
import { buildingBlocksHandlers } from './api/buildingblocks';
import { checklistHandlers } from './api/checklist';
import { paragraphsHandlers } from './api/paragraphs';
import { projectsHandlers } from './api/projects';
import { tasksHandlers } from './api/tasks';

const ARTIFICIAL_DELAY_MS = 2000;

export const handlers = [
  ...tasksHandlers(ARTIFICIAL_DELAY_MS),
  ...checklistHandlers(ARTIFICIAL_DELAY_MS),
  ...projectsHandlers(ARTIFICIAL_DELAY_MS),
  ...buildingBlocksHandlers(ARTIFICIAL_DELAY_MS),
  ...paragraphsHandlers(ARTIFICIAL_DELAY_MS),
];
```

```js
// database
import { factory } from '@mswjs/data';

import {
  buildingBlockFactory,
  generateMockBuildingBlocks,
} from './factory/buildingblocks.factory';
import {
  checklistFactory,
  generateMockChecklist,
} from './factory/checklist.factory';
import { paragraphFactory } from './factory/paragraph.factory';
import {
  projectFactory,
  generateMockProjects,
} from './factory/project.factory';
import { taskFactory, generateMockTasks } from './factory/task.factory';

export const db = factory({
  task: taskFactory(),
  checklist: checklistFactory(),
  project: projectFactory(),
  buildingBlock: buildingBlockFactory(),
  paragraph: paragraphFactory(),
});

generateMockProjects(5).map((project) => db.project.create(project));

const projectIds = db.project.getAll().map((project) => project.id);
generateMockTasks(20, projectIds).map((task) => db.task.create(task));
generateMockBuildingBlocks(10, projectIds).map((block) =>
  db.buildingBlock.create(block)
);

const taskIds = db.task.getAll().map((task) => task.id);
generateMockChecklist(20, taskIds).map((item) => db.checklist.create(item));
```

#### Project Slice

I will shorten this one as well to the relevant snippets.

```js
// projects.slice.js
import {
  createAsyncThunk,
  createEntityAdapter,
  createSelector,
  createSlice,
  current,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { client } from 'mocks/client';
import { HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

const projectsAdapter = createEntityAdapter();
const initialState = projectsAdapter.getInitialState({
  status: 'idle',
  filter: { type: null, value: null },
  statuses: {},
});

export const fetchProjects = createAsyncThunk(
  'projects/fetchProjects',
  async () => {
    const response = await client.get('https://my.backend/mock/projects');
    return response.data;
  }
);

export const saveNewProject = createAsyncThunk(
  'projects/saveNewProject',
  async (data) => {
    const response = await client.post('https://my.backend/mock/projects', {
      ...data,
    });
    return response.data;
  }
);

export const projectSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'projects',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // irrelevant reducers....
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(HYDRATE, (state, action) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('HYDRATE', action.payload);

        const statuses = Object.fromEntries(
          action.payload.projects.ids.map((id) => [id, 'idle'])
        );

        return {
          ...state,
          ...action.payload.projects,
          statuses,
        };
      })
      .addCase(fetchProjects.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(fetchProjects.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        projectsAdapter.addMany(state, action.payload);
        state.status = 'idle';
        action.payload.forEach((item) => {
          state.statuses[item.id] = 'idle';
        });
      })
      .addCase(saveNewProject.pending, (state, action) => {
        console.log('SAVE NEW PROJECT PENDING', action);
      })
      .addCase(saveNewProject.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        projectsAdapter.addOne(state, action.payload);
        console.group('SAVE NEW PROJECT FULFILLED');
        console.log(current(state));
        console.log(action);
        console.groupEnd();
        state.statuses[action.payload.id] = 'idle';
      })
      // other irrelevant reducers...
      },
});
```

This should be all the relevant code. If you have questions, please ask them and I will try to answer them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed how the state gets hydrated, so I turned this code:

```js
      .addCase(HYDRATE, (state, action) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('HYDRATE', action.payload);

        const statuses = Object.fromEntries(
          action.payload.projects.ids.map((id) => [id, 'idle'])
        );

        return {
          ...state,
          ...action.payload.projects,
          statuses,
        };
      })
```

Into this code:

```js
      .addCase(HYDRATE, (state, action) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.group('HYDRATE', action.payload);

        const statuses = Object.fromEntries(
          action.payload.projects.ids.map((id) => [id, 'idle'])
        );

        state.statuses = { ...state.statuses, ...statuses };
        projectsAdapter.upsertMany(state, action.payload.projects.entities);
      })
```

I used the adapter to upsert all entries.